# How to get rid of or clear out the Finder Recent Files

Tags: finder

The most ridiculous option is that the only option to get rid of Recent files is to delete the item.

I have searched all my possible options to control/remove/stop the Recent Files being shown on the Finder (Finder » Go » Recents), but no luck.

I have tried [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) with a setup of showing `0` Recent files, but it does not work on the Finder Recents that I'm talking about.

Why is there no option to remove the Recent Files from the Finder?

Why such an inconvenience be a feature of a renowned Operating System?

How to modify such behavior of the Mac Finder Recents directory?

Comment: The Recents menu is just searching for files by last opened date. Removing the GO menu option won't disable the ability to find recent files. You cannot just modify system applications like that. Just don't use that (very hidden) menu.

Comment: I think you need to explain why having a feature in the menus that you personally don't use is an inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to **prevent** a file from being displayed in the **Recents** directory/space. To prevent a file from being displayed in the **Recents** space, place the file inside a hidden directory. Only in that case, Mac will respect your privacy.

Using Secret Files

[image: using secret files]

Made them visible in the **Recents**

[image: they are visible in the Recents]

Make the original directory hidden

[image: make the original directory hidden]

Hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to Show/Hide hidden Files/Folders

Now they are gone from the **Recents**

Comment: That might work if you want to prevent files within a specific folder from showing up in any search for recently changed files. How would this scale to work for all files?

Comment: Also, it is still possible to use Terminal and use `find`, so this doesn‘t actually hide anything.